# Hit-Count (reads) of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

For evaluating an algorithm I have to count how often the items of a byte-array are read/accessed. The byte-array is filled with the contents of a file and my algorithm can skip over many of the bytes in the array (like for example the Boyer–Moore string search algorithm). I have to find out how often an item is actually read. This byte-array is passed around to multiple methods and classes.

My ideas so far:

1. Increment a counter at each spot where the byte-array is read. This seems error-prone since there are many of these spots. Additionally I would have to remove this code afterwards such that it does not influence the runtime of my algorithm.
2. Use an ArrayList instead of a byte-array and overwrite its "get" method. Again, there are a lot of methods that would have to be modified and I suspect that there would be a performance loss.
3. Can I somehow use the Eclipse debug-mode? I see that I can specify a hit-count for watchpoints but it does not seem to be possible to *output* the hit count?!
4. Can maybe the Reflection API help me somehow?
5. Somewhat like 2), but in order to reduce the effort: Can I make a Java method accept an ArrayList where it wants an array such that it transparently calls the "get" method whenever an item is read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an out-of-the-box solution but I'd probably just wrap the byte array in a simple class.

```
public class ByteArrayWrapper {
  private byte [] bytes;
  private long readCount = 0;

  public ByteArrayWrapper( byte [] bytes ) {
    this.bytes = bytes;
  }

  public int getSize() { return bytes.length; }

  public byte getByte( int index ) { readCount++; return bytes[ index ]; }

  public long getReadCount() { return readCount; }
}
```

Something along these lines. Of course this does influence the running time but not very much. You could try it and time the difference, if you find it is significant, we'll have to find another way.

Comment: hi biziclop,could you include/modify to include the main method as well,so that we can look into the example later

Comment: @Deepak Sure but I don't really understand what you mean. What is the `main()` method supposed to do?

Comment: I meant `how would the main method look like for above implementation`? Could you modify to include the `public staic void main method(String args[])`,highly appreciated since i do not know how to trigger the program ?

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do it this way!

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is to add some code injection.  However this is likely to be much more complicated to get right than writing a wrapper for your byte[] and passing this around. (tedious but at least the compiler will help you)  If you use a wrapper which does basicly nothing (no counting) it will be almost as efficient as not using a wrapper and when you want counting you can use an implementation which does that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use EHCache without too much overhead: implement an in-memory cache, keyed by array index. EHCache provides an API which will let you query hit rates "out of the box".

Comment: This sounds like overkill to me: bring in an external library for a thing that can easily be written in a small wrapper.

Comment: A fair point; on the other hand it avoids reinventing the wheel. Perhaps it depends on one's confidence/proficiency in writing something.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this automatically with a real `byte[]`. Using [JVM TI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/) might help here, but I suspect it's overkill.

Personally I'd write a simple wrapper around the `byte[]` with methods to `read()` and `write()` specific fields. Those methods can then track all accesses (either individually for each byte, or as a total or both).

Of course this would require the actual access to be modified, but if you're testing some algorithms that might not be such a big drawback. The same goes for performance: it will definitely suffer a bit, but the effect might be small enough not to worry about it.